# Eliminemos la etiqueta [javascript-objeto]

Tags: discusión, etiquetas, solicitud-de-quemado

Hay 13 preguntas con la etiqueta [javascript-objeto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript-objeto), que no ayuda a entender el asunto, porque realmente no suelen referirse a la programación orientada a objetos. Y aunque así fuera en algún caso, lo correcto sería usar juntas las etiquetas [javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) y [poo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/poo) (o su sinónimo [orientación-a-objetos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/orientaci%c3%b3n-a-objetos)).

Además no ayuda que la gente confunda JSON con "objetos javascript"

Comment: si son 13, con eliminarlas alcanza y se borra sola a la noche la etiqueta...

Comment: ¿Eso evitaría que se vuelva a usar? ¿Cuando se ha de quemar una etiqueta para evitar su reaparición?

Comment: Cuando la usan muy mal seguido... si es por pocas preguntas, va a desaparecer y nuevos usuarios no la van a poder crear.

Comment: @gbianchi ¿No te enojas si revierto tus ediciones en las que retiras la etiqueta en cuestión? Supongo que en la mayoría de los casos, si no es que en todos, sería revertir a la edición en la que la agregué :D

Comment: En cualquier caso habría sido bueno no quitar la etiqueta sin más, sino aprovechar para añadirle la etiqueta [tag:poo] (y esperar un poco a ver más opiniones, @gbianchi :P)

Comment: Concuerdo con fedorqui, aunque se tenga el poder de eliminarlas no se deberia hacer si no hay concenso.

Answer (score 1):

Lamentablemente llegué muy tarde y ya no hay preguntas con la etiqueta [javascript-objeto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript-objeto). Me hubiera gustado revisar esas preguntas que la tenían, casi estoy seguro que la tenían preguntas en las que las respuestas clarificaban la diferencia entre JSON y un objeto de JavaScript.

Si bien cada ves JavaScript incluye más características para manejar los objetos acorde a poo / orientación a objetos en algunas versiones que están en uso, como ECMAScript 5, no están disponibles.

---

Uff, logré rescatar el wiki de etiqueta

> Usar para preguntas que traten sobre la declaración y manejo de
>   objetos en JavaScript.
>
> No confundir con [objeto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/objeto) la cual se refiere a los objetos en el
>   paradigma orientado a objetos lo cual es un alcance más amplio.
>
> Tampoco confundir con [json](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/json) la cual se refiere al formato de
>   intercambio de datos usando texto simple.
>
> Etiquetas relacionadas
>
> - [javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript)
>
> Referencia
>
> - [Trabajando con objetos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Trabajando_con_objectos)

Recién agregué el resumen de etiqueta y para que no se pierda la etiqueta mientras llegamos a una conclusión, he agregado la etiqueta a una pregunta que no la tuvo antes.

---

Buscando las preguntas [Etiquetadas con javascript json en la pestaña Activas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript%2bjson?tab=Active) encontré las siguientes:

- [¿Cómo puedo convertir un string JSON a un objeto en JavaScript?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/1648/65)
- [¿Que diferencia hay entre declarar un objeto JSON con : y =?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/111625/65)
- [¿Cuál es la diferencia entre JSON y un objeto en Javascript?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/164943/65)

Encontré un lindo patrón que seguramente ayudará a encontrar las otras, todas fueron editadas "una tras otra" por el mismo miembro de la comunidad,  :)

Otro lindo patrón es que que you agregué la etiqueta en cuestión, también "una tras otra" (al menos las tres enlazadas arriba)

Comment: No estoy de acuerdo con esto. Javascript es un lenguaje como cualquier otro. Una etiqueta js-obj no es mas que la misma etiqueta del lenguaje. Si no, tendriamos una para cada lenguaje que pueda o no manejar objetos. no tenemos una php-obj. Cual seria la orientacion de uso de esta etiqueta?

Comment: El sitio no tiene un límite de etiquetas. ¿Cuál sería el problema de tener una etiqueta sobre objetos para cada lenguaje? En cuanto al a orientación de uso, todavía está en el wiki de etiqueta y para prevenir que se pierda he puesto una copia aquí

Comment: que son meta etiquetas. no aportan nada a la etiqueta principal. Y sobre meta etiquetas ya hemos discutido.

Comment: @gbianchi No son meta etiquetas pues su uso es específico. Las meta etiquetas son las que su uso es demasiado amplio como los sería [tag:tabla], [tag:sentencia], [tag:script].